# Re-entering US when STEM OPT expires in less than 6 months

Tags: student-visa, customs

My US F-1 STEM OPT expires in May 2019 and I am planning to travel outside US in Dec 2018. If I return to US in first week of Jan 2019, my STEM OPT will be valid for less than 5 months when I try to enter. Will that be a problem? More importantly, will it be an even bigger problem while boarding the flight to US since airlines may strictly require 6 months validity whereas CBP may be more lenient, or not?

I have valid passport, valid F-1 visa (valid till 2020), valid EAD card (till May 2019), valid I-20 (till May 2019), and a job.

Comment: There is a 6 month validity rule for passports (with exceptions for some nationalities) but not for visas, EADs or I-20s.  You shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travelling outside the USA while on Optional Practical Training (OPT)](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13459/travelling-outside-the-usa-while-on-optional-practical-training-opt)